# Outlook: Dragging folder into subfolder, folder list skips back

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-outlook, drag-and-drop

A usability issue in my opinion:

Background:
I use a lot of folders and subfolders ...

- e.g. Top level is "Task state"
  (e.g. similar to: Assigned, Received, Active,Needs Info, Report, Closed),
- subfolders are one for each Task,
- and one folder contains all emails and info regarding that task.

To keep track of a single task it has to be dragged between the top folders, but also into an Archive as it has been closed and the "Waiting time" has expired.

As there are a number of folders, the list is longer than can be displayed in the folder pane, even if the window is maximized.

At times there is a need to drag a Task-folder a long way in the folder pane.

If that is done today, **the folder list jerks back** to where the folder was picked up.
I find this annoying to say the least.

**Might there be something one can do to get rid of the jerking?**

---

*The 'right click' > 'move folder' opens up a ridiculously tiny dialog:*
*350 by 296 pixels showing 13 of you folder tree 'lines'.* *On a 2K monitor that is 15% of the available width, but more importantly a cripplingly tiny amount of detail, "line-wise".* *The overview is limited, i.e. crippled.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compared with a long way drag, what about manually right click the folder you want to move and choose "Move folder" to move it to your destination accurately.

Comment: Ahh... one more day, forgetting to try out this...

Comment: Well, that is a different way of doing it. Once again with a tiny dialog.